# visual studio: debugger doesn't start app after deploy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, deployment, visual-studio-2015

My problem is that after I debug my program it wont load my app and this is the only thing I get to see: http://prntscr.com/98oybj
I couldnt find it on google and makes is very frustrating.
I get no error or something when building but the app doesnt start.
Even after waiting it still doesnt start the application. Even thought VS says ''deploy succeeded''

This is really annoying and this also happens at other projects. Btw I didnt make this code by myself, it is from the book: microsoft visual c# step by step 2013.

Here is the code:

```
public sealed partial class GraphWindow : Page
{
    // Reduce pixelWidth and pixelHeight if there is insufficient memory available
    private int pixelWidth = 12000;
    private int pixelHeight = 7500;

    private WriteableBitmap graphBitmap = null;
    private int bytesPerPixel = 4;
    private byte[] data;

    private byte redValue, greenValue, blueValue;
    private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = null;

    public GraphWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        int dataSize = bytesPerPixel * pixelWidth * pixelHeight;
        data = new byte[dataSize];

        graphBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(pixelWidth, pixelHeight);
    }

    private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tokenSource != null)
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
        }
    }

    private void plotButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        redValue = (byte)rand.Next(0xFF);
        greenValue = (byte)rand.Next(0xFF);
        blueValue = (byte)rand.Next(0xFF);

        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = tokenSource.Token;

        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        try
        {
            generateGraphData(data, 0, pixelWidth / 2, token);
            duration.Text = string.Format("Duration (ms): {0}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        catch (OperationCanceledException oce)
        {
            duration.Text = oce.Message;
        }

        Stream pixelStream = graphBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
        pixelStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        pixelStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        graphBitmap.Invalidate();
        graphImage.Source = graphBitmap;
    }

    private void generateGraphData(byte[] data, int partitionStart, int partitionEnd, CancellationToken token)
    {
        int a = pixelWidth / 2;
        int b = a * a;
        int c = pixelHeight / 2;

        for (int x = partitionStart; x < partitionEnd; x++)
        {
            int s = x * x;
            double p = Math.Sqrt(b - s);
            for (double i = -p; i < p; i += 3)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                double r = Math.Sqrt(s + i * i) / a;
                double q = (r - 1) * Math.Sin(24 * r);
                double y = i / 3 + (q * c);
                plotXY(data, (int)(-x + (pixelWidth / 2)), (int)(y + (pixelHeight / 2)));
                plotXY(data, (int)(x + (pixelWidth / 2)), (int)(y + (pixelHeight / 2)));
            }
        }
    }

    private void plotXY(byte[] data, int x, int y)
    {
        int pixelIndex = (x + y * pixelWidth) * bytesPerPixel;
        data[pixelIndex] = blueValue;
        data[pixelIndex + 1] = greenValue;
        data[pixelIndex + 2] = redValue;
        data[pixelIndex + 3] = 0xBF;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you deploying the app?

Comment: I am pretty  new to this so I try to give you as much information as I can. It debugs as winrt(the universal windows 8.1 (store) app development). There hasn't change any settings though so it uses the standard debugger for win 8.1 applications.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check the Error List and Output windows in Visual Studio (both under the View menu). Then report any error messages here. Sorry, but I could not see anything on your screen-shot and I don't have sufficient privilege to make this a comment.

Comment: There are no error and there are also no warnings. That is the screenshot I get to see when visual studio debugs. Normally the app would start after that screen but it stays stuck??? This is what the xaml window shows:http://prntscr.com/994wqf. this is what I get:http://prntscr.com/994x0r. After I stop with debugging the screen stays open, but it should actually close like every app.